# html audio loop loops only the first song

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I am in front of a stupid problem.  I use the following code:

```
<audio id="musicPlayer" autoplay loop>
    <source src="resources/mp3/YouOnlyDisappear.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="resources/mp3/9Crimes.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="resources/mp3/MermaidBlues.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="resources/mp3/NowIsMine.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="resources/mp3/Untitled.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Only the first song is looped.  I tried to close source tags with />, or with , nothing will do, it's like only the first source is taken into account.  Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source tag is not meant to be used to provide multiple tracks, but rather, multiple versions of the same track. So the browser thinks all your secondary URLs are not links to other tracks, but merely alternate links for the same track (this is useful if you want to provide the same file in multiple formats in case a browser doesn't support a particular format). You'll probably have to use JavaScript (or merge all your tracks into one mp3) if you need to loop through multiple tracks.

edit: [Here's more info about the source tag and how it is intended to be used.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I failed to see in the example that it was the same source name with different extension.  It's still a pity that what I want to do is not as easy as I thought it would.  I guess that's a pretty common problem.  Thanks anyway!